# WordPress Menu Falls Back to Default Settings when moved to header

Tags: php, html, wordpress

When I have my wordpress menu code in my index.php file everything works fine. The wrapper in a  tag with the appropriate ID but when I move the navigation code to my header file or any other file and include it in my index template the navigation wrapper becomes a  and does not have the appropriate ID's any clue whats going on? Here is my code

FUNCTIONS.php

```
<?php
    register_nav_menus(
    array(
    'main-nav-header-top' => 'Main Nav'
        )
    );    

    $main_menu_header_top = array(
        'theme_location' => 'main-nav-header-top',
        'container' => 'nav',
        'container_id' => 'mainNavigation',
        'menu_id' => 'mobileNav',
        'depth' => 0,
        );


?>
```

And here is my code I want to put in my header.php file

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( $main_menu_header_top ); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( array('menu' => 'Main Nav' )); ?>
```

and don't forget to check the appearance → Menus panel.

you can debug using  [`get_registered_nav_menus()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_registered_nav_menus) to see if the menu is registered correctly ..

also ..

You will be better off wrapping it in a function and hooking to init ...

```
function my_custom_menus() {

    $locations = array(
        'header_menu' => __( 'main-nav-header-top', 'Main Nav' ),
        'footer_menu' => __( 'Custom Footer Menu', 'text_domain' ),
        'mobile_footer' => __( 'Footer Menu on mobile devices', 'text_domain' ),
    );
    register_nav_menus( $locations );

}

add_action( 'init', 'my_custom_menus' );
```

Answer (score 1):

remove **dashes** and replase with **underscore**

`main-nav-header-top` to `main_nav_header_top`